# How to graph a text as a function of some arbitrary parameters?

Tags: graphics, functions, style, text

I'm trying to graph a text in a couple of plots I have. I want to be able to edit the text depending on the values I choose (rho0, zp, zm, temp, ion, and perm) and show them at some point in my plot (X,Y) . I'm using the following code in order to achieve it

```
rho[rho0_, zp_, zm_, temp_, ion_, perm_, X_, Y_] := 
 Graphics[Text[
   Style[{rho0 " M, " zp ":" zm ", " temp " K, " ion " \[Angstrom], " perm}, 
    Black, Italic, 16], {X, Y}]]
```

However when I input

```
rho[0.001, 1, 1, 278.15, 4.25, 78.5, 1, 1]
```

Mathematica returns

```
{92.7978,:K,M,\[Angstrom],}
```

But what I expect to get is the text

```
0.001 M, 1:1, 278.15 K, 4.25 \[Angstrom], 78.5
```

What do I need to change in order to get this output?
Thanks on advance

Comment: `rho[rho0_, zp_, zm_, temp_, ion_, perm_, X_, Y_] := 
 Graphics[Text[
   Style[ToString[rho0] <> " M, " <> ToString[zp] <> ":" <> 
      ToString[zm] <> ", " ToString[temp] <> " K, " <> ToString[ion] <>
       " \[Angstrom], " <> ToString[perm], Black, Italic, 16], {X, 
    Y}]]`

Comment: Don’t multiply strings and symbols. Use Row to put them in order